# Neo4j Cypher query which returns the nodes along an arbitrarily long path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo graph that if I choose certain relationships, is a tree.

I would like to start at an arbitrary node and find all nodes up to the root.  I want returned to me all the nodes in between the two, including the ends. I need the nodes in order, in the case of the example, "a, t, c, d, e, ROOT".

Imagine the tree has a branch that looks like

```
a-[]->t-[]->c-[]->d-[]->e-[]->ROOT
```

If the relationships I care about are x, y, and z, and if the root node is called ROOT, and the starting node has a certain id (unique value), I get something like this:

```
(a {id:an_id})-[*:x|y|z]->(root:ROOT) return a, root
```

That returns me the ends, but how do I also get the nodes between them?

**edit**

nodes(...)  http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-collection.html#functions-nodes

Comment: btw. it's Cypher with an `y` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got it almost right:

You have to assign your expression to a path, .e.g. `p`.

```
MATCH p= (a:Leaf {id:an_id})-[:x|:y|:z*]->(root:ROOT)
RETURN p,a,root, nodes(path);
```

it might be more efficient to use shortestPath

```
MATCH p= shortestPath((a:Leaf {id:an_id})-[:x|:y|:z*]->(root:ROOT))
RETURN p,a,root, nodes(p);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll move to the deck, fire up the work machine, and read 'path' docs. You have parenthesis around your 2nd example but not the first. Does it matter?  And in the first example, where does 'path' come from?

Comment: the parenthesis belong to the shorestPath function.